# How do we integrate flutter with mux data?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a video streaming app in Flutter, using Mux. I also want to track user data to help recommend more specific videos per user. However, I do not know how exactly to integrate mux/data with the video_player plugin in flutter. Have I misunderstood how exactly these plugins/services work? I am using flutter for my frontend and python for the backend.

Links:

video_player: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

mux/data: https://docs.mux.com/guides/data/track-your-video-performance

Comment: Did you find a way to do the integration ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use this player instead which is functional: https://pub.dev/packages/mux_player

However, I'm struggling to make it autoplay and not go fullscreen when you play it as it feels kind of weird. It does track all data as you would expect.